# 4 bit multiplication with a 4-bit adder

Tags: cpu-architecture

Im doing a homework problem for computer architecture and im stumped on using a 4-bit adder. Here is an example problem which I thought I understood, and after that is my attempt but im incorrect. Any idea why?

[image: from the slides]

and heres my attempt at 0111x1101. I have done this correctly with an 8-bit adder.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the step 2 line, the second part of the product isn't correct ( should be 1011, not 0111).